# Function of walking down the tree structure with setting paths

Tags: python, tree

I've spent couple of hours and still unable to get the best result. However, the task is very easy but it seems I'm missing something or simply slow today.

So, we have a simple tree structure of objects. Object in formal looks like this:

```
node:
    name {str}
    value {str}
    children {list}
        node,
        node,
        ...
```

I need to create the `walk` function that outputs the list of all nodes in the format of list of tuples:

```
for node in topNode.walk():
    path, object = node
```

where `path` is obviously a path to the current node (i.e. `/name/name`). Almost the same does `os.walk()` function.

At the moment I'm in stuck with this piece of code:

```
def walk(self):
    result = []
    for child in self.children:
        result.append(child)
        result.extend(child.walk())
    return result
```

How to add `path` in here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to what you wish the output to be.

Comment: Indeed. I'm definitely slow today. Updated.

Comment: I interpreted it to be a list of paths and a list of objects returned as "path" and "object" respectively ... but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @mgilson You are right. I was my fault.

Comment: @VisioN :  Your edit implies the output should be a list of iterables of the form (path, object) which is different than a list of paths and a list of objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work -- I cooked it up in my head and haven't tested it...

```
 def walk(self,_root='/'):
     result=[]
     for child in self.children:
         path="%s%s/"%(_root,child.name) if child.children else "%s%s"%(_root,child.name)
         result.append((path,child))
         result.extend(child.walk(_root=path))

     return result  #result if _root != '/' else zip(*result)
```

**EDIT**

Fixed the return statement to match your edit above.

Answer (score 3):

Do whatever you have to do with `child` in order to get the composite path, and then pass on `child.name` as  a parameter of walk (it can even be a keyword argument).

Something like...

```
def walk(self, path=''):
    result = []
    for child in self.children:
        child_path = path + '/' + child.name
        result.append((child_path, child))
        result.extend(child.walk(child_path))
    return result
```

Comment: This won't unpack the way it is supposed to, but it's basically the same idea that I used, so I guess maybe it was a valid approach...

Comment: Yeah, I guess OP edited the question right after you started.

Comment: Also, there's no way for the paths to start with a single '/' as desired...But otherwise a good solution I think.

Comment: @mgilson: what do you mean? Paths will start with '/'. OK, the root element is not included in the path, but I'm not sure whether OP wanted that.

Comment: Basically, I don't really care on how many slashes are in the beginning.